# BindingSource from multiple SQL tables

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I have a simple project in which I am in need of having a database containing three tables. The database is implemented using SQL Server Compact Edition, as a `.sdf` file. The following information about the program might be a little bit irrelevant but I include it nonetheless.

The tables are as follows:

```
Student
Course
SelectedCourse
```

The `Student` table is the master table that contains personal info about each student. The `Course` table contains several courses that can be selected for the student. The `SelectedCourse` contains a student registration number and a course number. The relations between the tables are set in the database.

Now, I have never before used several `BindingSource` that are connected to different tables, and I have found very little information about this. What is the correct way to present information from my tables?

1. Should I have one `BindingSource` in all, that has all the information from all the tables?
2. Should I create several `BindingSource` that connect to a table each, and then has a relation to a "master" `BindingSource`?

I have a `DataSet` that contains all the tables, though I am unsure whether or not I should have one for each.

I am not new to SQL, I'm just trying to figure out my way around how to bind a database to controls in Visual Studio using the in built tools that are provided. I could hardcode everything using SQL select statements, thought I figure I would lose the idea of using Visual Studio as a programming aide.